# Get $_POST without diacritics

Tags: php, html, forms, echo, diacritics

I used this type of form:

```
<input type="radio" name="song" value="Jedna pesnička v hudobnom želaní"><strong>ONE</strong> <br>
<input type="radio" name="song" value="Dve pesničky v hudobnom želaní"><strong>TWO</strong>
```

But when I need value using php:

```
<?php echo $_POST["song"]; ?>
```

I will receive:

> Jedna pesniÄŤka v hudobnom ĹľelanĂ

I want to receive:

> Jedna pesnička v hudobnom želaní

How can I enable diacritics. Is here some easy, elegant way?

Comment: Normally I won't use complex string for value. Simple string / integers instead. (then map with your complex string with dictionary-like array)

Comment: What charset did you set for the document?

Comment: make sure you use utf-8 charset

Comment: but where? in php file where I have that echo I have correct charset in meta, everything is with diacritics, only that one value when I used echo no

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you're code editor is set to the charset you are using.

Secondly, make sure the page is telling the browser to use your selected charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Thirdly, make sure PHP  is sending the correct HTTP response headers:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')
```

If you are storing these on a database, you'll also need to make sure the tables will store the correct character set.

If problems persist, checkout PHP [multi-byte string functions.](https://www.php.net/mbstring)